# Unable to redirect to LoginUI using @SpringUI(/login) when using Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, vaadin

I have a project where I've integrated Vaadin with Spring Boot. One of the dependency that I use is spring-boot-starter-security.

When I invoke the url http://localhost:8080/appXYZ/ it redirects me to http://localhost:8080/appXYZ/login.  I'm expecting it to go to my LoginUI class with has the annotation @SpringUI("/login").  It does not, I'm redirected to some other page which has a username/password form.

pom.xml: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4cc27b3d9e59f67839bf
Application.java (which starts the Spring Boot app): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6748b81d26b486dc617c
LoginUI (where I'm trying to go): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a98f5099d5daa27fb391

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick experiment where I commented out all the Spring Security stuff.
When I tried the url http://localhost:8080/appXYZ/login, I did get to the LoginUI page.
Just have to fix the issues with Spring Security. But the @SpringUI("/login") redirect is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also overwrite the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method in your `MySecurityConfigurer` and specify a login page for Spring to redirect to when the user is not authenticated and is trying to access for example the **/authorized** path, while allowing access for all users to **/login** and other adjacent resources (/VAADIN, /UIDL, etc).

The following snippet is extracted from my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227505/integrate-spring-boot-starter-security-with-vaadin-7/29647922#29647922) as they are in close relation:

---

I changed a bit the `ApplicationSecurity.configure(HttpSecurity http)` method to `http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();` and I was able to proceed to the second screen. Now this may not be that safe from what I gathered, but it should give you a starting point.

Note: You may already know this but if you don't and it saves you some time I'm glad to share this as well, because it took me a while to figure it out. Depending on how you will setup your app security you may end up changing that method to something like below.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().
            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")).accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/VAADIN/**", "/PUSH/**", "/UIDL/**","/login", "/login/**", "/error/**", "/accessDenied/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/authorized", "/**").fullyAuthenticated();
}
```